# django: assign None value if not existed in QueryDict

Tags: python, django

I'm looking for a better way to code:

My Code is,

```
@login_required 
def updateEmInfo(request):        
    userProfile = request.user.get_profile()
    if request.POST.__contains__('userType'):
        userType = request.POST['userType']
    else:
        userType = None

    if request.method == 'POST':
         ~~~~~~~~
```

If I code as `userType = request.POST['userType'],` then I get an error if `userType` is not equal.

I don't think it is good idea to to use the `__contains__` method, is there a better way to write this code?

Something easy like the following

```
userType = request.POST['userType'] ? request.POST['userType'] : None
```

Comment: Just one note: instead of using `__contains__` you should use `in` (`if 'userType' in request.POST`). But in this case Jesse's answer is accurate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use [`get`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get)

`request.POST.get('userType')`

> get(key[, default]) Return the value for key if key is in the
>   dictionary, else default. If default is not given, it defaults to
>   None, so that this method never raises a KeyError

.

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
userType = request.POST.get('userType', None)
```

This would be roughly equivalent to:

```
try:
    userType = request.POST['userType']
except KeyError:
    userType = None
```